# Other party member stopped running in the field

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Recently while running around and doing side quests, I noticed that Noel was missing. I assumed that he had gotten stuck somewhere, like my Mog had gotten in the past, but when I found him he was instead walking very slowly toward me. I figured it was just a one-time thing, but nothing seems to help correct the problem.

Here are things that I've tried:

- Reloading the save.
- Switching party leader.
- Changing location through the Historia Crux.
- Enter and exit battles.
- Press random buttons...

You get the idea. While it's not game breaking, it does break my immersion a bit when Noel decides to take a stroll at the other side of the area.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Gah, I feel stupid for not trying this, but instead of just reloading the save, restarting the game completely seemed to fix the problem. Should I make an answer with this conclusion, despite its simplicity?

Comment: Yes.  It's a simple answer, but it's an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Maybe you need to switch leader more often so Noël doesn't feel so left out? Then you could be friends again! ;)

Comment: Haha, I have indeed neglected to use Noel since the start, maybe he  has gotten fed up with it by now. :) I assume Serah was showing her  dissatisfaction with the way I treated Noel by also refusing to run when I switched to him temporarily. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't try this earlier, but it seems restarting the game instead of just reloading the save fixed the issue.